# Why does eclipse create a .settings directory?

Tags: java, eclipse

i have noticed that eclipse recently creates a .settings directory with 1 file inside and i am wondering if i should add this to version control? SVN?

also, is this new? i have been using  eclipse for quite a while, but never noticed it.

the contents of the file in the directory is this:

```
#Sun Oct 11 14:57:03 CEST 2009
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
```

shouldnt these settings be workspace-wide and not project specific?

Comment: Good question. I think its a bit of a silly name for eclipse to choose. What happens if we already have a dir for that in our project? Most apps use their own name; e.g. `.svn` , `.git`, `.hg` I don't know why not `.eclipse`.

Comment: @JW. I guess Eclipse chose the name `.settings` rather than `.eclipse` because they want other IDEs to follow this practice.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This file records project specific settings vs. workspace preferences.

I noticed that this file is usually created when you convert a regular Java project to Java EE project.

The only time I would check this file in is when the project's compiler/warning settings are different from the default workspace settings.

This may be the case when some legacy projects cannot be compiled with the latest and greatest java compiler, or when the source code generated by a 3rd party produces a lot of warnings that are benign but pollute your `Problems` view.

If you are going to use project specific settings, then definitely check this file in.  Otherwise delete it.

Comment: If your version-control system supports making the file writable (File Type in Perforce) then you may want to do that.  Otherwise, with the Error Log window up, I see (we have a project named Common):
Could not write to read-only file "/Common/.settings/language.settings.xml".

Answer (score 20):

The .settings folder is used by various plugins to set persistent 'Properties' as opposed to 'Preferences' to specify project specific settings that should be preserved.

This is usually a directory you most definitely want checked into svn/cvs/git etc as it will ensure that all users who check that project out into eclipse use the right project specific settings.

In our case we use it to supply a minimum compiler version of 5 since some devs are on Java 5 versus 6 etc but we want things compiled to 5 for our servers. We also use it to enforce some coding standards and auto-formaters which makes version diffs much easier to read.

In your specific case you selected 'Enable Project Specific Settings' under "Properties->Java Compiler" by right clicking on the project and choosing properties.

Comment: This answer is better than the chosen one IMHO.

Comment: If your version-control system supports making the file writable (File Type in Perforce) then you may want to do that.  Otherwise with the Error Log window up, I see (we have a project named Common):
Could not write to read-only file "/Common/.settings/language.settings.xml".

Answer (score 3):

Those are project specific settings for eclipse.  You do not need to include them in svn, as each users eclipse will create these when they checkout project, or they may even use another IDE and not need them.  If you are the only one using the project then it won't matter if you include them though.

Comment: Personally I disagree with this.  If you have a policy, for example, of only supporting Java 5 (or 1.4, etc.), then you *don't* want developers overriding these settings.  You want to check in the files and be able to track changes to them.

Comment: if someone actually checks them into version control, pain ensues if vcs like clearcase is used that mandates files should be read-only. Eclipse really doesn't like .settings to be read-only. Just a word of warning...

Comment: I guess Eclipse chose the name `.settings` rather than `.eclipse` because they want other IDEs to follow this practice.

Comment: To follow up on @eis, if your version-control system supports making the file writable (File Type in Perforce) then you may want to do that.  Otherwise, with the Error Log window up, I see (we have a project named Common):
Could not write to read-only file "/Common/.settings/language.settings.xml".