# Java open existing project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java.. Eclipse etc. We have a working Java application, all the .java files and .class files are available in the file system. The .jar file is executed once a hour and it does it job. Now the developer is gone leaving behind this application.

I dont want to touch the existing set-up. So I have downloaded this Eclipse Standard/SDK Kepler Service Release 2 on my laptop and want to try out some modifications.

After googling "how to open existing java appl in Eclipse" gives very useful info, but none is of use to me. I did File > Import > General etc. etc. but Eclipse keeps saying "No projects are found to import".

In the file system where I have my .java files the project it seems is split into multiple folders, i.e if I open the main source folders, there are 10 sub folders and all contains .java files. I also know from the production environment that all those 10 folders .java files are used.

So I have this .java and .class and .jar file. So how can I import it into Eclipse on my laptop.

Comment: Surely the source code (etc.) is in your source control system?  You shouldn't need to "open" the Jar itself.

Comment: Honestly, it is _very_ optimistic to think that you can change the application in a useful way with this state of knowledge. If this is a crucial application you need to hire someone to do this.

Comment: @his so what do you suggest, should I quit development and look for alternate career?

Comment: No! Definitely not. I don't know if you are doing this for learning purposes. Then I have to admit that I think it is a weak approach. You need to learn fundamentals systematically, not by just doing something random. If it is a real task that needs to be done then you can't expect to do it without _prior_ knowledge. I absolutely don't know you personally but from the question it is clear that you _just now_ will not be productive if this is a real task.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have the source code but it's not an eclipse project.
Try to see [How to create a project from existing source in Eclipse and then find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636201/how-to-create-a-project-from-existing-source-in-eclipse-and-then-find-it)

Comment: It was made using Eclipse

Comment: Are you able to find a .project file inside the root folder?

Comment: On prod I have under the directory 4 folders; .settings, src, bin, doc and 2 files .classpath and .project

Comment: seems .setting file is missed. setting file contains information related to project and workspace refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551008/why-does-eclipse-create-a-settings-directory